# object from form data not processing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, object

I have this form that I am trying to process. It is your basic address form. When it submits I send it to the processing script at the bottom here. The problem that keeps occurring is that when I submit the form the script just repeats the first address over and over equal to the amounts of different address data that were entered. I'm using a .each function to traverse the inputs and then place them into a function turning the data into an object and storing it into an array. I then process that data later.

The following is the form that I am using below. I am pretty sure that nothing is wrong here, the only thing I could think of is that the name is interfering with the class but I can't see that happening at any point considering I never call the name, and am using an ajax call to get my data on the server side. Please note that this is a snippet of a much larger form, so please do not point out that I am missing the form tags.

```
<span class='address-form'>
        <div class='row'>

            <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <label>Street Name and Address</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control address not-empty' name='adress[]' value="<=$address?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <div class='col-md-6'>

                                <input type='text' class='form-control address2' name='address2[]'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <div class='col-md-3'>
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control city not-empty' name='city[]' value="<?=$city?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-3'>
                                <label>State</label>
                                <select class='form-control state not-empty' name='state[]' value="<?=$state?>">
                                    <option value="" selected>--State--</option>
                                    <?=listStates($state, $us_states)?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-2'>
                                <label>Zip</label>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control zip not-empty' name='zip[]' maxlength='5' value="<?=$zip?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <div class='col-md-3'>
                                <label>From</label>
                                <div class='input-group app-input'>
                                    <select class='form-control app-md-input addr_from_month not-empty' name='addr_from_month[]'>
                                        <option value="" selected>mm</option>
                                        <?
                                        for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++){
                                            print "<option value='".$i."'>$i</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    <select class='form-control app-md-input addr_from_year not-empty' name='addr_from_year[]'>
                                        <option value="" selected>yyyy</option>
                                        <?
                                        $year = date("Y");
                                        for($i = $year; $i > ($year - 25); $i--){
                                            print "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span></span>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-3'>

                                <label>To</label>
                                <div class='input-group app-input'>
                                    <select class='form-control app-md-input addr_to_month not-empty' name='addr_to_month[]'>
                                        <option value="" selected>mm</option>
                                        <?
                                        for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++){
                                            print "<option value='".$i."'>$i</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    <select class='form-control app-md-input addr_to_year not-empty' name='addr_to_year[]'>
                                        <option value="" selected>yyyy</option>
                                        <?
                                        $year = date("Y");
                                        for($i = $year; $i > ($year - 25); $i--){
                                            print "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
```

Below is the validation script. As I stated earlier in the question, I am using a .each function but after further review of how the function works, I am starting to find that it is in accurate, and is not working as it should. I'm not sure of another method to attempt, and since it is an indefinite amount of items, I can't exactly use a for or foreach loop.

```
var addresses = []; //holds array of address objects

$('.address').each(function() {
        address = new newAddress($('.address').val(), $('.address2').val(), $('.city').val(), $('.state').val(), $('.zip').val(), $('.addr_from_month').val(), $('.addr_from_year').val(),     $('.addr_to_month').val(), $('.addr_to_year').val());
    addresses.push(address); //build the addresses array of objects
});

function newAddress(line1, line2, city, state, zip, from_month, from_year, to_month, to_year){
    this.line1 = line1;  
    this.line2 = line2;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.from_month = from_month;
    this.from_year = from_year;
    this.to_month = to_month;
    this.to_year = to_year;
}
```

Thank you ahead of time for any input and answers that I receive. I will provide edits and additional information as needed!

Comment: Within your loop you're missing the use of `$(this)`, ie: `$('.address').val()`. This will bring up always the first element in the selected result.

Comment: can you explain in depth a little further?

Comment: Well, what's the point of looping through all the elements with `class` `address` if within this loop you're always getting the first element in the set, by selecting again `$('.address')` and so on? The purpose of the loop would be to select the element referred by `$(this)` which would be the one returned on every iteration.

Comment: [.each() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: so use $(this) only in front of address, or in front of each of the different selectors

Comment: The other selectors are made of other `classes`. Your code would need to be re-written, starting with the selector used in the `.each()` loop. Your problem here is logical (algorithm), not with `jQuery`, `Javascript` or anything else.

Comment: ah okay, I see where you are getting at, if you want to submit any of this as a reasonable answer, I'll accept and throw you some rep for the assitance

Comment: @mark will **<span class='address-form'>** repeats on the form  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my comments, I think this would be a quick fix to your problem:

```
$('.address').each(function(index) {
    address = new newAddress($('.address').eq(index).val(), 
        $('.address2').eq(index).val(), 
        $('.city').eq(index).val(), 
        $('.state').eq(index).val(), 
        $('.zip').eq(index).val(), 
        $('.addr_from_month').eq(index).val(), 
        $('.addr_from_year').eq(index).val(),
        $('.addr_to_month').eq(index).val(), 
        $('.addr_to_year').eq(index).val());

    addresses.push(address); //build the addresses array of objects
});
```

---

**Update**

Another way would be using `.map()` to return the `array` in one go. The code below would be everything you would need:

```
var addresses = $('.form-control').map(function (index, element) {
    return {
        line1: $('.address').eq(index).val(),
        line2: $('.address2').eq(index).val(),
        city: $('.city').eq(index).val(),
        state: $('.state').eq(index).val(),
        zip: $('.zip').eq(index).val(),
        from_month: $('.addr_from_month').eq(index).val(),
        from_year: $('.addr_from_year').eq(index).val(),
        to_month: $('.addr_to_month').eq(index).val(),
        to_year: $('.addr_to_year').eq(index).val()
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: this is excellent thank you very much, i was never aware of the .eq function in the jquery library. That's why I love this place I learn something new everyday, you're great dude. Thank you so much for your help again!

Comment: No problems. I'm working on a complement for this answer, just in case you decide to go for a different approach.

Comment: that would be interesting to see just for the sake of understanding different concepts, but the result you first provided has worked out perfectly.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another way of doing that.

Comment: so from how I see this here, this just eliminates the process of needing the second function to generate the object in general, and builds the array of objects just right there?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would be _similar_ to `anonymous objects` in `C#`, for example.

Comment: dammit man you're a genius! :) I have never used C# but I have been meaning to indulge myself in it for the purpose of web development. I hear it is a rather useful language.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan! :) As a side note, I would recommend that you go for the `MVC` pattern, having `ASP.NET / C#` + `Razor` + `SQL Server` + `HTML5` + `LESS (CSS)` and `Javascript/jQuery`. To make things easier for templating, you could also include `Bootstrap` to this mix. You can find loads of good tutorials over the web to start cracking on.

Comment: noted, do you have a good place to get started on learning the basics of C#

Comment: Good starting points: http://www.asp.net/mvc and http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5